# Get data from table by County in a single row

Tags: mysql

I want to get data from table in a single row for single county. Right now as shown in images it shows Different rows for Single county as Kalamazoo. It should show single with both records in single row.

I am using following query

```
SELECT County, Virus, SumOfPositiveTests 
FROM StatewiseData 
WHERE State = 'MICHIGAN'
```

[image]

I want the results to be shown as following

```
County        Virus        SUMOFPOSITIVETESTS
---------------------------------------------
Kalamazoo     H3N2,H3N8      3
```

Total sum of both H3N2 and H3N8

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (The answer will probably be product specific...)

Comment: Specify the wanted result!

Comment: Different columns in the row, or combined to a single column?

Comment: @AnkitKhettry Result sould be Kalamazoo H3N2,H3N8,3

Comment: Apologies for my harsh language in the previous comment. I learnt from certain sources that mysql alone actually allows you to query non-aggregate fields as well, though the results can be misleading. Posted an answer, hope it helps.

Comment: try my answers @DilshadAli

Comment: @AnkitKhettry, that MySQL group by behavior has been corrected in more recent versions. (But there's a compatibility mode that can be set if required to keep old applications running.)

Comment: @jarlh I am unaware of what the result will be if we do not aggregate a field and still query the same. Although I am fairly sure that either the query would throw an error, or the result will be misleading. The GROUP_CONCAT function seems to be a aggregate function itself, which is why it must be working.

Comment: Do you only want Kalamazoo county, or all Michigan counties, or just those  counties that appears more than once?

Comment: try my answer @DilshadAli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use MYSQL  `GROUP_CONCAT`

The following MySQL statement will return a list of comma(,) separated 'Virus's for each group of 'County' from the StatewiseData table

```
SELECT County,GROUP_CONCAT(Virus),sum(SumOfPositiveTests) FROM StatewiseData  where State='MICHIGAN' group by County
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using mysql:

```
SELECT country, GROUP_CONCAT(virus) _virus, SUM(SumofPositiveTests) as TotalPostitiveTest 
FROM StatewiseData
WHERE Country = 'Kalamzoo'
GROUP BY Country
```

Please mind that this will not work with most databases, as they need you to to specify only the grouping field and aggregate functions of other fields in your query.

Here is the [source](https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/)

Comment: Thanks Let me try this

Comment: Shouldn't it be `where State='MICHIGAN'`?

Comment: That can be added if required, the focus is on displaying the comma separated values of virus i believe.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. this would work on IBM DB2 and MySQL. what DB you are using

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country, Virus,SumOfPositiveTests FROM Customers where State='MICHIGAN'  group by Country;
```

Comment: This probably won't work, u can only have the grouped by(i.e. Country) or aggregate columns (like sum, count etc) in the query. Although I am still not sure what the user is trying to ask.

Comment: Invalid. And no aggregating.

Answer (score -1):

why are you using `state` in where condition? (please provide list of columns do you have in a column if i missed something)
if you are only selecting the country then it should be as simple as:

```
SELECT County,Virus,SumOfPositiveTests FROM StatewiseData where Country='Kalamzoo'
```

if you want to select summary or totals of single country then you you should use sum like:

```
SELECT country, SUM(SumofPositiveTests) as TotalPostitiveTest 
FROM StatewiseData  WHERE Country='Kalamzoo' GROUP BY Country
```

Comment: can you please tell me why you just downvoted my answer?

Comment: I suppose someone did because you're not aggregating virus. Or because newer MySQL won't accept the group by. Perhaps. (It wasn't me.)

Comment: @jarlh, haha. This makes may day:  "(it wasn't me)"

Comment: I try to be fair, I rarely downvote answers, and never without commenting.

Comment: +salute, and so do I. down voting was somehow fine, but providing no comments or reason will make everyone of us (specially the victim XD) puzzled.

Comment: Totally agree. I very seldom downvote and if I do, I feel it a responsibility to comment on the post. Having said that though, I am taking my +1 vote back, since this doesn't solve the main problem :P